# PHP - Parsing String From HTML File

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Hey guys I'm parsing a bunch of data from an html file in PHP using the `preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlPage, $matches)` method (regular expressions) and am having some issues creating the pattern for the following string: `href="http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/putlocker.php?id=12VT1372H42OKWGKW" target="_blank"><div>TV Show Season 2 Episode 1`.

The pattern consists of two strings with a wildcard string in the middle.  This should be fairly simple but I am having trouble escaping the proper characters in the strings on either side of wildcard string.  Here is an example of a pattern I have tried.

```
//Pattern escaping " and < charecters
$patern = "/href=\"http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/.*\" target=\"_blank\">\<div>TV Show Season 2 Episode 1/";
```

I have tried a couple other patterns but all failed.  In all attempts I use the regular expression `.*` to signify the wildcard string.  What is the correct pattern to parse all occurrences of this string out of an HTML file?

Comment: So the html file contains valid HTML?  then regex should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2lc

```
preg_match("/href=\"http\:\/\/www\.free\-tv\-video\-online\.me\/player\/.*\" target=\"_blank\">\<div>TV Show Season 2 Episode 1/", 'href="http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/putlocker.php?id=12VT1372H42OKWGKW" target="_blank"><div>TV Show Season 2 Episode 1', $output);
```

$output will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => href="http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/putlocker.php?id=12VT1372H42OKWGKW" target="_blank"><div>TV Show Season 2 Episode 1
)
```

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, I used the pattern outlined above.  It didn't work at first but I took another look at the HTML page and I was missing some `\n` and `\t` characters but I got it to work! Thanks @bagonyi

Answer (score 1):

Try also escaping your inner `/` characters:

```
"/href=\"http:\/\/www.free-tv-video-online.me\/player\/.*\" target=\"_blank\"><div>TV Show Season 2 Episode 1/"
```

Comment: I think that may be it because I know that `/` are used to define new patterns in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You added an extra /. 9th character on the second pattern. Just take it out.

Edit: Now the first pattern since you've edited the original post.

Comment: I'm really sorry I think that is a product of improper translation on my behalf.  I just updated the original question.

Comment: That pattern matches the string you provided. What else do you require?